# Possessive noun and sarcasm quotes

Tags: punctuation, possessives, irony

I use sarcasm quotes like so:

> Let's ask the "expert".

But with a possessive noun, is the following the correct way, or isn't there one?

> Let's ask for the "expert's" advice.

Comment: Is it the use of the apostrophe inside the quotation marks you don't like the looks of? If so, you can use *the so-called expert's advice*, dispensing with the quotation marks altogether.

Comment: According to this source, the Chicago Manual of Style says not to turn titles in quotation marks into possessives; I'd suggest the same principle applies here.  https://markallenediting.com/2016/04/15/possessive-of-a-title-in-quotes-just-dont/

Comment: @StuartF - the article that you link to has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: *...is the following the correct way,...?* Yes, it is.

Answer (score -1):

A- Let's ask for the "expert's" advice.

B- Let's ask for the expert's "advice".

Both imply something wrong. A implies either that the person isn't an expert, or that experts don't exist at least in this context. B could imply the same things PLUS that the advice isn't really advice - maybe it's an order.

For most circumstances, either would work so no rule.